# Updating the html <select> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[solved]
So i have code below which should check the value of the first drop-down selection menu with the id="country" and based on the value currently selected it will change the drop-down options of the second menu. Below is my attempt to solve this problem however it does not work :( any help?

EDIT: I'm starting to think that the value of 'var country' is not being updated when it is manually changed, could it be that onChange does not work? i'm using chrome so it should be supported.

```
     <div id="forum2">
     <form action="#forumhandler.php">
       <fieldset>
       <legend>Shipping Calculator</legend>
       Country:<br>
          <select id="country" onChange='fieldcheck()'>
           <option value="us">United States</option>
           <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          </select>
       <br><br>
       Province/State:<br>
        <select id="state" >
          <option value="s1">Ontario</option>
          <option value="s2">Quebec</option>
        </select>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>

<script>
        var country = document.getElementById("country");
        var state = document.getElementById("state");

        function fieldcheck() {
            if (country.value == "us") {
                state.options[0].value = "U1";
                state.options[1].value = "U2";
            } else if(country.value == "canada"){
                state.options[0].value = "C1";
                state.options[1].value = "C2";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Errors in your console?

Comment: im using notepad++ and i  unfortunately don't have the debugger n console plugins installed.

Comment: so you expect us to debug it for you? What browser are you using that does not have developer tools??

Comment: lol ya i see now, i have no console errors. n i wonder if my name helped you give me that -1 x)

Comment: you have errror when you do change the selected country, because the country id is null, try to see the console in inspect elements such as firebug

Comment: @Willyanto Halim but shouldn't the  " onChange='fieldcheck()' " call the function anyways when a field is manually selected?

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your script tag right before the closing body tag. In its current position, it's trying to determine the value of state, which is null because the element with the id of "state" doesn't exist when that document selector line runs.

Comment: "Try putting your tag right before the closing tag" , sorry but im not sure what that means, does that mean i put the script tag after the closing tag of the div with the id="forum2"?

Comment: The standard organization of html elements is:

    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
    </html>

Your content lives between the opening `<body>` tag and the closing `</body>` tag. The recommended location for your `<script>` tag is right before the closing `</body>` tag. Meaning after all other content within the body. This ensures that whatever manipulations you're attempting to make to DOM elements will work since those elements will have been loaded on the page. If you attempt to make changes to elements before they're added to the page, your code won't run properly.

Comment: i tried to put my script tag after the closing tag of  <div id="forum2"> ,  before the closing tag of  <div id="forum2">, and after/before the closing body tag. After checking, i was still not able to output the desired results when i ran the page. (i didn't upload all of my code in the space above, but all that code above is within the body tag - here is how i organized by tags <html><head></head><body></body></html>)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var country = document.getElementById("country");
    var state = document.getElementById("state");
});

function fieldCheck() {
    if (country.value == "us") {
       state.options[0].value = "U1";
       state.options[1].value = "U2";
    } else if(country.value == "canada"){
        state.options[0].value = "C1";
        state.options[1].value = "C2";
    }

     alert("first option value is " + state.options[0].value + " and second option value is " + state.options[1].value);
}
</script>
```

here is work code for you. hope it helps

Comment: thank you for the reply, but unfortunately that code also does not work.

Comment: you can see the result in inspect element, you just want to change the value or the whole option?

Comment: yess thanks babe! i was trying to update the .innerHTML but i was just updating the value x..) suupper thank you, i wish i could give u some nice points <3.